# I get weird characters when trying to convert a byte array to a string

Tags: java, oracle, utf-8, arrays, clob

I an reading data in from a oracle Clob field, and storing it into a byte array. I was using a Clob because a varchar2 did not have sufficient size for some of the fields.

I am using this java code to convert the byte array

```
    String s1 = Arrays.toString(byteArray);
    String s2 = new String(byteArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).trim();

    System.out.println(s1);
    System.out.println(s2);;
```

s1 ouputs as

```
[0, 84, 0, 1, 2, 12, -128, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 101, -74, -97, 0, 1, -106, 20, 0, 1, 47, -101, 0, 41, 0, 41, 3, 105, 0, 1, 0, 65, 0, 84, 0, 84, 0, 82, 0, 73, 0, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, -110, -125, 16, -93, 9, 111, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -116, 81, 2, -62, 27, 50, 0, 50]
```

s2 outputs as
[image]

The expected output is

```
ATTRIBUTE19 + ATTRIBUTE16
```

Can anyone give me some insight on what maybe causing these strange characters in the result string?

[EDIT]

I have also just tried updating one of the clob fields to be 1 character 'T' this was the result
[image]

I find this weird as this field does not have the word LAST in it, yet 2 of the other fields do. The contents of those fields are

```
(LAST_ENTRY == '') ? '' : $BON_AWARD_PCT_1 * $BON_BASE / 100
```

and

```
(LAST_ENTRY == '') ? '' : doRound($BON_AWARD_AMT_1 / $BON_BASE * 100,'0.01')^IF($BON_BASE = 0,0,$BON_AWARD_AMT_1 / $BON_BASE * 100)
```

Comment: What was the original encoding before storing as CLOB?

Comment: ISO-8859-1, though even when I try StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1 it comes out the same as above

Comment: The data does not look like UTF-8 encoding of the expected output. It does not look like UTF-8 at all, more like a UTF-16. I would expect a sequence 65, 84, 84 repeated twice in the byte sequence; it's there only once, so there's some random data mixed with the text that you expect.

Comment: So it could be the data coming from the database has some hidden characters that i'm not seeing causing the results to screw up?

Comment: Just "ATTRIB" in maybe UTF-16LE is seen. It seems text is gone. Maybe written was with inappropriate use of ObjectOutputStream/DataOutputStream. Or some weird kind of Hufmann compression for 2-byte chars.

Comment: Is this the _whole_ content of your `CLOB` ? Are all rows screwed up like this ? Do you have other sample rows -- very small: maybe 0 char length or 1 to 3 char length ? That might give us some clues...

Comment: @SylvainLeroux, I've added some additional information. Hope this helps. Also to answer your other question all the rows do come out like this.

Comment: All of this is very puzzling ?!? Do you have access to the code that *write* into the DB? Maybe the issue is coming from there...

Comment: its just a simple update script, UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET FIELD_NAME = 'blah' @SylvainLeroux